# subprocess.check_output('dir',shell=True) producing FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to run a script that I've successfully run on a few other machines, and for some reason I keep getting this error when I run it on this particular machine. It's windows 10, but so is my other one, not really sure what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_output('dir',shell=True)
```

The full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output('dir',shell=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you open command prompt and try to run `dir` ?

Comment: You should share your script... or at least the part of it that crashes.

Comment: dir runs fine from the promt

Comment: import subprocess

subprocess.check_output('dir',shell=True)

Comment: Does it behave differently when you leave `shell=True` away? (or use `shell=False` explicitly)

Comment: same result regardless of shell=True or shell=False, or left off entirely

Comment: I also have UAC turned down to never notify, as well as being an admin account (only account) on this machine

Comment: What is `os.environ['COMSPEC']`?